# Jquery Ajax form select change div fadeout error

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax, show

i'm a new user of ajax and i have a little problem on div function.

Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('select.age').change(function(){
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'change_age.php',
            data: {selectage: $('select.age').val(), projectId: $('input[name$="projectId"]').val()},
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function()
{
$("#msg_age").html('<span style="color: #00BB00;">Changement OK</span>').fadeOut(4000);  
}
});
});
});
```

My form page test.php

```
 <form action="#" method="post">
 <label for="age">Votre Age</label>
 <select class="age" name="age">
 <option value="18">18</option>
 <option value="19">19</option>
 <option value="20">20</option>
 <option value="21">21</option>
 <option value="22">22</option>
 <option value="23">23</option>
 <option value="24">24</option>
 <option value="25">25</option>
 <option value="26">26</option>
 </select>
 <input class="projectId" type="hidden" name="projectId" value="1"/>
 <div id="msg_age"></div>
 </form>
```

My change_age.php

```
<?php
$query=mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
mysql_select_db('database',$query);
$selectage=$_POST['selectage'];
$id=$_POST['projectId'];
$sql='UPDATE tests SET name="'.$selectage.'" WHERE id="'.$id.'"';
mysql_query($sql) or die("Error: ".mysql_error());
?>
```

When i go on my form for 1st time, i change an option the changement is ok, i wait 4 seconds the div fadeout.
When i select another select, nothing appear, i must to refresh the page ..
I wanted to show again the message with the fadeout if another select is selected.

Someone have an idea ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Try adding call to `.fadeIn()` before `.fadeOut(4000)`; e.g., `$("#msg_age").html('<span style="color: #00BB00;">Changement OK</span>').fadeIn(0).fadeOut(4000)`

Comment: Wow! works perfectly !!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I would create span for notifications in your template, give it own id, and `.fadeIn()`/`.fadeOut()` it when it's needed.

Less DOM manipulations and better performance.

So, your code will be like :

```
...
success: function() {
  $("#msg_age").fadeIn(150).fadeOut(4000);  
}
```

Next, long-time fading out don't look friendly, I would better use `.delay()` for that

```
...
success: function() {
  $("#msg_age").fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut();  
}
```